# Task failed: Activating language client: HtmlLanguageClient

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2022

I've faced this problem anytime I open my Visual Studio and then open any of my Razor view files (.cshtml). The problem of image below appears and I lose lots of helpers and intellisense, speeding down my work a lot. *Can't post this on super user community because lack of reputation to attach images there.*

[image: screenshot of message]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Searching on Microsoft feedback, I've opened on ticket on my own and find one workaround for those who don't find any guidance so far. Basically, the workaround is to rename caching folder of language server to Visual Studio recriate a correct new one version. (Links on end of this answer).

> Can you try deleting the WebTools\Languages\LanguageServers\ComponentModelCache folder contents (or rename the folder), and let me know if you still hit the issue? I haven’t been able to reproduce yet, and I’m trying to narrow down if this is an issue generating the cache from a clean state or updating the cache from a prior version.

For those who not want to read the links below, the folder mentioned above is **%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_\WebTools\Languages\LanguageServers\ComponentModelCache**. Rename or delete this folder, than reopen Visual Studio and the problem is "solved".

[image: screenshot of folder mentioned to rename or delete]

Links of Microsoft Feedback tickets:

[My ticket: More objective](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Task-failed:-Activating-language-client:/10017435)

[Original Ticket: More information](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Task-Failed---Activating-language-client/1616964#T-ND10017441)

Comment: I seem to get into this situation every time a new VS update is installed. Either way, this solved my issue, thank you.

Comment: This helped me too. Although we shouldn't have to go into the bowels of Visual Studio's cache to format our razor files.

Comment: I just recently updated to Visual Studio (Enterprise) 2022 version 17.7.2 and this workaround has seemed to have stopped working. I also recently installed the Preview version 17.8.0 Preview 1.0, which installed .net8 which is in preview.

Comment: Like with @GeneralMac installing the 17.8 Preview broke this for me too (in non-preview version of VS 2022 Enterprise)

Comment: I did notice that when I used @Lari 's method and did a good old fashion restart, things started working again. Unfortunately, I can't be sure that this was the fix.

Comment: This works as well for other language servers such as Razor. Sometimes it gets stuck in an infinite loading and will not work whatever you do.